# Print elements in `O(j)`?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, structure

I have `N` individuals, and want to do elections.

For each individual I want to save how many voted to him and how many votes he gave to others in `O(1)`.

( I have already done that part by declaring an array whose length is `N` with two attributes in each cell; `taken` and `given`.
When 1 votes to 2 then I increase `taken` for individual 2 and `given` for individual 1 by one.)

How may I print all individuals who didn't get any votes in `O(j)` where `j` is the number of those individuals?

I can use `O(N)` space only. (please explain the idea not the code)

**Note:** I know only arrays, lists and doubly linked lists.
**(please explain the idea not the code) and I want to initialise the data structure in O(1)**

Comment: If you're not showing/asking for code, then the C++ tag seems unnecessary.

Comment: You can store a linked hash set of individuals (size N) and remove them from the set (constant time amortized) whenever they're voted for, leaving you with a hash set of size J, iterable in J time because of the linked list.

Comment: A linked hashed structure combines a linked list with a hash map, guaranteeing specific performance. A brief overview for Java is here, but can be implemented in any language: https://www.java67.com/2012/08/difference-between-hashmap-and-LinkedHashMap-Java.html

Comment: if you have full list of candidates in an array, then whenever you find a candidate who has either received or cast the vote , you can delete that candidate from that array. final array will have only users who has not received or cast their vote

Comment: This user reposted this question with more detail here:  [Job Interview Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729337/job-interview-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

If you get your list of N individuals and split it into 2:

- One list containing the individuals that got votes, let's call this `V`;
- One list containing the individuals that did not get votes, let's call this `J`.

You would initially have all your individuals in the same list (`J`), and as they get votes, you remove them from one list (`J`) and put them in the other (`V`).

Assuming that you are not to count the overhead needed to maintain 2 lists, this should still satisfy your O(N) space constraint, since |N| = |J| + |V|.

So depending on the results you want to print, you would iterate on the appropriate list. If you need to print all the information, you would then iterate over both.

As per your question, to get the topmost K individuals with the most number of votes in O(K), you can:

1. Assuming that you do not have any constraints on how data is inserted/updated, you can resort the list on each and every insert/update operation. This way, when you need to read the content of the list, then you know for a fact that the list is already sorted, with the best performing individual at the beginning of the list.
2. Slightly similar but with more going on behind the scenes, you can look at the [Map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) data structure. As you can see, there is a `compare` function which can also be provided. As per the documentation, elements will be sorted according to the outcome of this `compare` function. Both options do the same thing, but in option 1 you are doing all the code, while in option 2, you are leaving the heavy lifting to the `Map` implementation.

Comment: @WhiteForce: If, as per your other comment for another answer, you cannot use Maps, then I am not sure how you can achieve anything in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap, Hashmaps have an access complexity of O(1).
in your case you can use the number of votes as a key and array of those who did not get any vote as a Value. this will allow you to access the array in O(1). and get anyone in the array in O(array length "which is j as you stated")

Comment: Iterating over a plain hashmap is typically linear in the address space of the map (i.e., its capacity) rather than in the number of elements stored. This distinction may matter, depending on the map's specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete code but this logic of creating hash map would work for you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-multidimensional-map-in-c/
// C++14 code to implement two-dimensional map
// and inserting value through insert()

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
   int vote_gain = 0;
   int vote_cast = 0;
    // First key type is a string 
    map<string, map<string, int> > m; 

    map<string, map<string, int> >::iterator itr; 
    map<string, int>::iterator ptr; 

    m.insert(make_pair("arun", map<string, int>())); 
    m["arun"].insert(make_pair("received", ++vote_gain));
    m["arun"].insert(make_pair("cast", ++vote_cast));
    for (itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++) { 

        for (ptr = itr->second.begin(); ptr != itr->second.end(); ptr++) { 
            cout << "The candidate " << itr->first 
                << " has  " << ptr->first 
                << " a vote " << ptr->second << endl; 
        } 
    } 
}
```