# Job Interview Algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, structure

**UPDATE: Can somone please answer my last comment on n. 'pronouns' m.'s answer?**

**Please Note:** I have asked this before but it was a complete mess so I am writing it with more details and in the original form.

**Question:**

I am managing a vote system between N participants (Each one indexed from 1 to N) where I want to support the following functions:

1. Init(N) - Initialise the data structure. -O(1)
2. Vote(j,i) - Add to the results table that person j voted (exactly 1) to person i - where It's not allowed for someone to vote himself. -O(1)
3. Voters(i) - Return the number of people voted to i. -O(1)
4. Origin(j) - Return the number of votes person j gave to others. -O(1)
5. Favored(k) - Print top participants (In descending order) according to the number of votes they got. -O(k)
6. Avoided() - Print all participants who didn't get any vote. -O(r) where r is the number of printed participants

In this question **space complexity** should be **O(N)**.

**Only allowed the use of arrays, and (doubly) linked lists.**

---

**What I did?**
I solved 1-4 so easily simply by declaring an array whose size is N and each cell contains to values; `got` and `sent`. when `i` votes to `j` I increase got value for `j` and sent value for `i` by one.

Still I have no idea on how to solve 5 and 6 in the required complexity.

**Note:** I'm looking for the algorithm/idea rather than an actual code.

Comment: And what is your actual question? Also you need to provide question related code, be more specific about your problem and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pzaenger thank you, I have made the necessary changes. Please let me know if anything is missing

Comment: Combination of map,set and priority queue should do the trick.

Comment: @nice_dev As mentioned: Only allowed the use of arrays, and (doubly) linked lists.

Comment: Maybe I can use the fact that when someone votes he gives *one* vote per time?

Comment: Initialising an array of N elements is O(N), so point 1 is not solved.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. [This is incorrect](https://thunderwiring.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/initializing-array-in-o1-c/).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I know a method to check if place is initialised or not in O(1) so you can forget about this

Comment: The restriction is a bit odd. Did the interviewee have a solution?

Comment: @WhiteForce Initializing an array can be done in `O(1)`, answered to comment claiming it's not solveable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the for each operation, the candidate that got voted for increased their score by exactly one.

This opens a new strategy - rather than mapping a candidate to its score, map a score to the list of candidates with this score.

This can be implemented quite simply as a list of lists candidates: (in template like syntax: `list<list<Candidate>>`).

In addition, keep an array mapping each candidate number, to the pointer of the actual `Candidate` element.

The list of candidates with 0, will be implicitly set to all candidates initially, in a [similar way you initialize an array in O(1)](https://thunderwiring.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/initializing-array-in-o1-c/).

- When a vote is cast:

1. You find the candidate from the reference: O(1)
2. You remove it from its current list, and add it to the next list: O(1)
3. To support `Avoided()` in `O(r)`: If the number of elements in the "0" list is smaller than half, change it to be a regular list instead.
4. If the previous element representing a score now has no candidates, drop it, and link the previous score to the next one directly, (i.e. if no candidate with score 3, connect `2<->4`) This ensures `O(n)` space due to not too much empty list nodes.

- Getting topK is now easy and done in `O(k)` by iterating the scores list from end to start (stopping after outputting `k` candidates)
- Avoided is now `O(n) = O(r)` if more than half the candidates were avoided, or `O(r)` otherwise thanks to optimization (3) in insertion.

Comment: @orlp Not quite. You can skip elements with 0 candidates in them, jump directly to the next score. At most `n` scores could exist, thus this meets the criteria. I'll elaborate on it.

Comment: Actually, I overlooked you have a list of lists - not a vector, it's fine. It's the same idea I was writing up but I was doing it using intrusive lists.

Comment: "Getting topK is now easy and done in O(k) by iterating the scores list from end to start" how I can iterate over linked list from the end? Plus in this case I need doubly linked lists right?

Comment: Another question, how may I know which number of votes a given linked list represents?

Comment: #3 is unclear. Changing an array to a list is an O(N) operation. When do you perform it?

Comment: @WhiteForce (1) Yes, you will need doubly linked list for that. (2) You can keep it in the `Candidate` object, for example. It can stored the number of votes and its identifier, and since in each list each candidate has the same votes, it's easy to find it by looking at first element. (probably can be optimized in real life, but for complexity analysis it will do).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It is `O(1)` amortized, happens in vote. Since you do it once after you already did `n/2`  votes, at least - it is `O(1)` amortized complexity (similar to standard hash table insertion, which might get reshuffled every once and then).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to implement Avoided(). Associate two numbers with each person who has been voted, the start-of-run and the end-of-run. Initially all elements are set to `None` (can be done with O(1) array initialisation trick).

When person `m` gets voted for the first time, update `startOfRun` and `endOfRun` arrays:

```
if startOfRun[m-1] != None and startOfRun[m+1] == None
   endOfRun[startOfRun[m-1]] = m
else if startOfRun[m-1] == None and startOfRun[m+1] != None
   startOfRun[endOfRun[m+1]]
else if startOfRun[m-1] != None and startOfRun[m+1] != None
   endOfRun[startOfRun[m-1]] = endOfRun[m+1]
   startOfRun[endOfRun[m+1]] = startOfRun[m-1]
else
   startOfRun[m] = m
   endOfRun[m] = m
```

(edge conditions omitted for brevity).

Now you have runs of persons who were voted for, and you can easily get from the start to the end of each run. Numbers inside the runs are all wrong but we don't care about them. There are O(r) runs so you can skip all who were voted for in O(r).

---

Here's an alternative way to implement Favored(). Have two arrays, (1) an expanding array of persons sorted by score, and (2) a map from a score to the index of the last person in the first array having score not less than that (if no such person, then `None`). Initially the first array is empty and the second one contains `None`s. Example:

```
(array 1)
(index)       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
person        3 6 5 1 4 2 8 9 7
score         7 7 7 5 5 3 2 2 2

(array 2)
score         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
index in 1st  9 9 6 5 5 3 3 - -
```

Once a person is voted for the first time, it is added to the end of the array with the score of 1, and `array2[1]` is updated. Once the person is voted for again, it is swapped with the first person in the array having the same score, the score is increased, and the second array is updated (we only need to update one element, the one that corresponds to the new score).

Comment: If you associate additional values with each participant, then initialization is not O(1).

Comment: @Sneftel They are all None initially.

Comment: Right, an operation that requires nulling each element individually.

Comment: @Sneftel there is a trick that allows one to avoid the O(n) cost of array initialisation for a price of space increase by a constant factor. There is a link in one of the answers. OP is already using it.

Comment: @WhiteForce (1) You use an array as a map (degenerate hash map).  (2) Try drawing it. Basically every element at either end of a run knows where the other end is, so when a run extends or two runs merge, we can update this information.

Comment: @WhiteForce Initially the array is empty so it is sorted. Each of the two operations (adding a new person to the tail with the score of 1 and increasing the score of an existing person) maintains the sorted invariant.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. you solution is wrong regarding Favored() Why the scores are from 1 to N they could be N random numbers at the end.... and the biggest one N^2 so you are allocating an array with N^2...

Comment: Hmm yes the biggest is N^2 so this doesn't quite work. It probably can be fixed by eliminating the score-to-person array and storing the "first person with the same score" in a list, with all the persons pointing to the same element of a list. But I don't have much time to think about it.

Comment: Avoided is wrong too, how can reach the runs and know in O(1) if a number in the runs or not? you have to scan them all I wish if you can only fix this one as I figured out a way to fix the latter @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: I don't understand this question